# mySQL: 1055 user.fieldName isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1055

I have a old SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT groups.groupID ORDER BY groups.groupID ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS groupIDs,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT languages.languageID ORDER BY languages.languageID ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS languageIDs,
    user_option.*, user.*
FROM user user
LEFT JOIN user_to_groups groups ON (groups.userID = user.userID)
LEFT JOIN user_to_languages languages ON (languages.userID = user.userID)
LEFT JOIN user_option_value user_option ON (user_option.userID = user.userID)
WHERE user.userID = 1 GROUP BY user.userID
```

On a new Server, I get this error:
1055 user.fieldName isn't in GROUP BY

How can I rewrite this query that this work? When i take all field in GROUP BY, it works. But I can add fields in the Table dynamic, so that I can't list all fields in Group By.

Thank you for help

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the alias `user user`? Try to use smth like `FROM user user1` and change `user` to `user1` in following text.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. In a properly designed  environment rows are dynamic and columns are not dynamic.

Comment: You can toggle off the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sqlmode on your new server to have it behave like MySQL prior to the 5.7 update where this is toggled on by default. [See Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html). Generally I would highly suggest writing better SQL, but you have already waded into the dynamic column anti-pattern, so toggling that sqlmode off is probably easier then fixing your not-so-great schema.

Comment: Thank you. This is a very old query from a other software. So I can't rewrite the complete software. Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY  is one change. Yes. But gives a simple way to rewrite this query? Dynamic is not 100% correct sorry. With a Admin Control Panel, I can add user options and have so more than this fields. And so I get allways a new error isn't in GROUP BY